# Displacement due to sinusoidal load on a finite strip in an infinite plane

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

From a paper on tunnel design I've been reading: (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0886779887900113)

> In the present application, the solu-
>   tion corresponding to a sinusoidal load
>   in an infinite elastic medium is sought.
>   Since no closed-form solution to this
>   problem exists, a numerical procedure
>   should be used. The procedure involves,
>   first, deriving the solution to the case of
>   a constant pressure applied to a finite
>   strip in an infinite body. The solution
>   for a sinusoidal distribution of loading
>   then can be found by dividing the
>   wavelength into several segments and
>   assuming the pressure on each segment
>   to be constant. In the present case, this
>   procedure is applied to calculate the
>   displacements under a sinusoidal line
>   load. Each wavelength was divided in 10
>   and 20 segments and a line load of 4, 6, 8
>   and 10 wavelengths were considered. It
>   was found that the calculated displace-
>   ments became insensitive to the number
>   of wavelengths when the latter exceeded
>   6, and that 10 segments were enough to
>   represent each wavelength.
>   As a result of this analysis, the vertical
>   displacement under a sinusoidal load
>   may be approximated by
>
> $$u_y = \frac{(3-4\nu)}{16\pi(1-4\nu)G}\sigma L\sin\frac{2\pi x}{L}$$

The authors refer to the plane strain solution to Kelvin's problem before this.

Can you suggest how I would go about deriving this as mentioned in the paper—from going for a finite strip in an infinite body to applying a *numerical* solution and getting the result for displacement?

Note: $\nu$ poisson's ratio, $L$ Length of strip, $G$ is the shear modulus.